# Least square error problem ill conditioning

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, matrix-equations, least-squares

I am trying to understand why I am getting an almost singular matrix in a problem I have.
The problem is a simple as
$$
\min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}} \left\lVert AX - B \right\rVert_F^2
$$

Obvioulsy in constructing $A$ and $B$ there're few steps. But I can overly simplify with a toy example the step I believe is causing the issue.

Suppose you have $f(x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ and define $T_y$ as $ (T_yf)(x) = f(x - y)$.
Suppose you have now $Y = \left\{ y_1, \ldots, y_n \right\}$.

Essentially I think my choice of $\sigma$ and $Y$ is such that I get something which is (numerically) linearly dependent. In theory I don't think this would happen but in practice that's my problem (numerically).

Is there maybe a theoretical/numerical method that tells me *how much*
$
\left\{ T_y f\right\}_{y \in Y}
$
are linearly indepedent?
(You can imagine that you later fix $\left\{ x_1,\ldots,x_m \right\}$ and then
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
T_{y_1}(x_1) & T_{y_2}(x_1) & \ldots & T_{y_n}(x_1) \\
T_{y_1}(x_2) & T_{y_2}(x_2) & \ldots & T_{y_n}(x_2) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
T_{y_1}(x_m) & T_{y_2}(x_m) & \ldots & T_{y_n}(x_m)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This in my calculation (numerically) is never full rank.
**Note**: $m >> n$.

Is there some study or measure I can use to work out better choices of $Y$ and $\sigma$?

Comment: I don't think I fully got it. Please let me give some thoughts.

Comment: Please let me know what is the first place that seems unclear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least when $c:=x_i-y_i$ does not depend on $i$, any $n\times n$ submatrix of $A$ is of the form $M=(f_c(u_i-u_j)\colon i,j=1,\dots,n\}$, where $f_c(x):=f(x+c)$. So, $\det M>0$, since the function $f_c$ (being the characteristic function of a normal distribution) is positive definite.

However, $f_c=f_{c;2}$ is only "borderline" positive definite, in the sense that for any real $p>0$, the function $f_{c;p}$ defined by the formula $f_{c;p}(x):=\exp(-|(x+c)/\sigma|^p/2)$ is positive definite if and only if $p\le2$. So then, $\det M$ may be very close to $0$ and hence $A$ may be very close to a non-full rank matrix.

The same will hold if for some permutation $\pi$ of the set $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ we have that $x_i-y_{\pi(i)}$ does not depend on $i$. A similar effect can be expected if $x_i-y_{\pi(i)}$ does not much depend on $i$ for for some permutation $\pi$ of $[n]$. Because there a great number ($n!$) of such permutations, it is likely that there is one with this "does not much depend on $i$" property.

---

There also is the general tendency for large $n\times n$ matrices to be close to singular. Indeed, the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues (repeated according to their multiplicities). So, if even one eigenvalue is very close to $0$, then the determinant may be close to $0$. This effect is exponentially strong in the number of eigenvalues close to $0$.

That is why different regularization methods, such as [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Tikhonov_regularization) and [Lasso method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Lasso_method), are used with the method of least squares.

Comment: I am digesting the answer. Can you clarify what you mean by "characteristic function of normal distribution". Also what do you mean by "borderline positive definite", how are you assessing the borderline?

Comment: I think I understand the idea. Which is a similar intuition as mine. What I was wondering however if there's some what to measure this ill conditioning (conditioning number could be one of it).

Comment: @user8469759 : For the definition of a characteristic function, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Introduction). For a characteristic function being positive definite, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties). For the characteristic function of a normal distribution, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples).

Comment: @user8469759 : I explained in the answer what I mean by "borderline" positive definite. What do you think is unclear in that explanation?

Comment: How is $f_{c;p}$ positive definite iff $p \leq 2$. Wouldn't this hold also for $p = 4$? (any even number).